# Pop-up alert message if it cannot retrieve the results from server in specified time

Tags: javascript

I want to create a JavaScript function, which should popup an alert when the user starts typing in the TextBox and the server couldn't retrieve the results in 3 seconds even though it contain the results.

**My current code:**

```
function keyup(e) {
    if(timeout != null) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = null;
    }

    if(jq('.ui-menu-item').is(":visible")) {
        time = performaceTiming.responseStart;
        timeout = setTimeout(bluff, 3000);
    }
    else {
        timeout = setTimeout(popup, 2000);
    }
}

function bluff() {
    alert('alert box inside bluff');
}

function popup() {
    alert('the requested name could not be found, please search for other name');
}
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing as to how the script works. Your code as is will call the `popup` function two seconds after the the user last typed something, if the menu item is not visible, or the `bluff` function three seconds after if the menu item is visible. There's nothing in the code presented which indicates anything about the results or a server call. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: yeah i knew that..i donno how to include that, so iam searching for a way to find that...how to pop-up if it cannot retrieve the visible results in the time lapse?can you please post an example if you knew how to?

Answer (score 0):

you don't call the functions named bluff or popup but the undefined variables, you should add () to call the function

```
if(jq('.ui-menu-item').is(":visible")){
    time=performaceTiming.responseStart;

        timeout=setTimeout(bluff(),3000);}
else{
    timeout=setTimeout(popup(),2000);
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply..yeah i added that too, i want to get that alert popup when it couldn't retrieve the result in 3 sec...but i donno how to achieve that, can you help me with that please!

Comment: This is actually bad advice. Doing it this way calls `bluff` or `popup` immediately, not at the timeout you've defined. You have it correctly in the original.